# Publishing my ASP.NET MVC project doesn't publish all necessary files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the publishing wizard and it published all of the necessary files except for my `Controllers` folder. I was under the assumption that I need a controller.

I have navigated to Package/Publish Web setting, do I need to tweak anything in here? I'm guessing this isn't set up properly out of the box. If I change the drop down to publish all files in this folder/solution will it try to upload all the referenced DLLs that don't need to be copied to the server?

Comment: Your controllers should be compiled into an assembly which then gets copied over. You actually should not have the source files on the server?

Comment: @Mike Geise, so both the models and controllers folder will not be copied over then?

Comment: Is there any reason to include Controller files because it's already present in the assembly and there is no need of it

Comment: @Nick, When you build your project it compiles your source files (controllers, models) into an assembly with the name of your project. Those the assemblies that should be copied over along with your view files and static content.

Comment: @Mike Geise, that makes more sense, however i'm still wondering why MVC compiles .cs files into dll's but ASP.NET doesn't.

Comment: @Nick, ASP.NET does compile them in assemblies you just don't notice it. MVC compilies them when you build your project. ASP.NET compiles them for your first request if they are in your App_Code directory.

Comment: @Mike Geise, to be clear "ASP.NET" doesn't compile them into the assembles, Visual Studio does. =)

Comment: @Mike Geise, I guess the next question is, why would someone want to file> new project vs file>new web site and vice versa... Is there a performance hit if you send the files without compiling first?

Comment: @Craig I was talking about source files dropped into an App_Code folder but if you want to get technical the CLR does all the work.

Comment: @Nick, for mvc its best to compile the source files into an assembly. Less of a headache but no there is probably no performance hit except for the first request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET web projects, including MVC projects, .cs files (controllers in this case) are compiled into the /bin/*[your.project]*.dll assembly when you do a Build or Publish.

So you don't need to publish/copy .cs files.

Comment: It is done in ASP.NET (if you do File -> New Project and select web). Not for ASP.NET Web sites.

Comment: The ASP.NET Web site option is more what your thinking of where you can just copy everything .cs, .aspx, whatever to the server and it all gets compiled at runtime. ASP.NET web project and mvc projects are pre-compiled (well.. except the markup because that's always compiled at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

The controller and model code is compiled into the web site dll. The views are deployed in their folders.

Comment: that is very interesting. What are the reasons for doing this? Is it so the web server doesn't have to compile it?

Comment: @Nick, you don't (and shouldnt) be doing that on ASP.NET Webforms as well. The cs files are not supposed to be copied over on the server for security + performance reasons.

Comment: @nEEbz, I'm surprised I never read that anywhere when I initially started learning webforms - yikes, I'll have to go back and compile those files.